# How to access the inputs next to current active input?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have several inputs,

```
<input type="text" name=ABC onkeyup='MyFunction(this)'>
<input type="text" name=ABC>
<input type="text" name=ABC>


function MyFunction(activeInput) {
     /*... some code here to create array 'thisArray', of length 3 whose values are to be assigned to the 3 inputs. ...*/
     activeInput.value = thisArray[0];
     /*... this is where i need help. How do i assign the other 2 values to other 2 inputs...*/
}
```

These inputs have no id, but have the same name. And no JQuery, only Javascript.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Could you eloborate on what you are trying to achieve? The code you are trying to write seems really backward and there is most likely a smarter solution to your problem

Comment: I am trying to add a functionailty to an already existing piece of code, and am unable to explain this further. getElementsByName did the trick. Thanks for ur time !

Comment: var siblings = Array.prototype.slice.call(activeInput.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('input'));

Answer (score 2):

```
//not tested
<input type="text" name=ABC onkeyup='MyFunction(this,0)'>
<input type="text" name=ABC onkeyup='MyFunction(this,1)'>
<input type="text" name=ABC onkeyup='MyFunction(this,2)'>


function MyFunction(activeInput,position) {
     activeInput.value = thisArray[position];
}
```

I think it would be easier with assigning and ID as well.

```
activeInput.value = thisArray[activeInput.id];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByName("ABC");
for (i = 0; i < thisArray.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].value = thisArray[i];
}
```

Comment: watch out that inputs[i] is defined!

Comment: Yes sure, ll add checks to avoid that.